# How to prevent Bluebird’s Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

So I have this code:

```
profileRepository.get(profileUuid).then((profile) => {
  if (profile.fileUuid) {
    profileStore.getFile(profile.fileUuid).then((fileData) => {
      data.fileData = fileData;
    }, callback);
  }

  data.profile = profile;
}, callback);
```

and I am getting the warning:

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
```

Which I believe is happening because `profileStore.getFile()` returns a promise too.  Now generally the way to get rid of that warning would be to chain the `then()`'s, doing something more like:

```
profileRepository.get(profileUuid).then((profile) => {
  if (profile.fileUuid) {
    return profileStore.getFile(profile.fileUuid);
  }

  data.profile = profile;
}, callback)
.then((fileData) => {
  data.fileData = fileData;
}, callback);
```

The issue is that I have to call `profileStore.getFile()` conditionally so I don’t see how I can use then chaining in this case nor do I see a way to re-write this code in any other way to prevent the warning from happening.  I tried `return null` from the `get()` success callback but that does not even prevent the warning.

The warning is just causing my console log to fill up which makes it really annoying when I need to do debugging and stuff, does any know of a way to prevent this warning with this use case?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried this with the same warning:

```
profileRepository.get(profileUuid).then((profile) => {
  if (profile.fileUuid) {
    return profileStore.getFile(profile.fileUuid);
  }

  data.profile = profile;
}, callback)
.then((fileData) => {
  data.fileData = fileData;
}, callback);
```

Comment: simple, return a promise from where it is telling you need to

Comment: Your usage of `callback` looks very strange.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, I tried that with the same warning (updated post).

Comment: @robertklep Not sure what you mean by strange, the `callback` is what needs to run if any promises are rejected.

Comment: In that case, why not use `.catch(callback)`?

Comment: @robertklep I could however that has nothing to do with the problem of the warning (yes I have tried it and I get the same warning).

Comment: Is the `profileRepository.get` call itself inside any handler?

Comment: @DonSteep no, it is not called within  any other handler

Comment: Then, I wonder if the reason is hidden within `profileStore.getFile` because there seems to be nothing (of the sort) wrong with your updated code block.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that I have to call profileStore.getFile() conditionally so I don’t see how I can use then chaining in this case

You don't need to use chaining here. But you always need to `return` the promise if you are doing something asynchronous in your  `then` callbacks, as otherwise the outer promise doesn't wait for it (and you don't want that).

In your case, you can return a promise for nothing from the callback so that it waits until `data.fileData` got assigned:

```
return profileRepository.get(profileUuid).then(profile => {
  data.profile = profile;
  if (profile.fileUuid)
    return profileStore.getFile(profile.fileUuid).then(fileData => {
      data.fileData = fileData;
    });
}).then(() => data, callback);
```